# Requests и Response

Tags: python, requests, response

Я прописываю код

```
import requests

response = requests.get('https://api.github.com')
response.text
```

Выводит это

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 212.4746.96)
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Почему не работает text ?

Comment: Что значит «не работает»? Почему вы решили, что не работает?

Comment: @andreymal должен ведь вывести что-то типо   '{"current_user_url":"https://api.github.com/user","current_user_authorizations_html_url":"https://github.com/settings/connections/applications{/client_id}","authorizations_url":"https://api.github.com/authorizations","code_search_url":"https://api.github.com/search/code?q={query}{&page,per_page,sort,order}","commit_search_url":"https://api.github.com/search/commits?q={query}{&page,per_page,sort,order}","emails_url":"https://api.github.com/user/emails","emojis_url":"https://api.g

Comment: Вы не написали никаких команд для вывода, поэтому этот код не должен ничего выводить

Comment: А в чём вы код запускаете? Если не в `ipython` (ну или там `Jupyter Notebook`) то ничего не напечатается если не сказать `print`